# Elastic Search Fliter on two fields within same sub document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to write an elastic search query where I have an array of sub-documents with exactly same structure and I have to check two conditions within the same sub document.

My data looks like this :

```
{
    "_id": "5672ba7c0d71c93d159c408e",
    "productId": "1723913526",
    "title": "Digitab Tablet",
    "instock": true,
    "specifications": [{
        "category": "In the box",
            "name": "Test1",
            "value": "No"
        }, {
            "category": "Warranty",
            "name": "Test2",
            "value": "Yes"
        }, {
            "category": "General",
            "name": "Test3",
            "value": "Abcd"
        }],
    }
}
```

What I am trying is : I should get products where specifications.name is "Test1" and specifications.value of the same sub document is "Yes"

Here is the Query that I have written for the this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "specifications.name": "Test1*"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "instock": "true"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "specifications.value": "yes"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

**The issue is** - It should not return the product with id 1723913526 because "value": "Yes" is true for "name": "Test2" and not for "name": "Test1".

I hope the question is clear, please comment if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your mapping to indicate that `specifications` is a [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type.

Mapping like:

```
"mappings": {
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      ...
      "specifications": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then querying like:

```
"bool": {
  "must": [{
    "nested": {
      "path": "specifications",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "wildcard": { "specifications.first": "Test1*" }},
            { "term": { "specifications.value":  "yes" }} 
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term": { "instock": "true" }
    }
  }]
}
```